# What should be rank of matrix with compositional data variables?

Tags: r, linear-algebra, compositional-data

I'm doing compositional data analysis on 'Baysite' dataset under 'compositions' package in r. Aim is to find nature of the relationship of its permeability to the mix of its four ingredients:

A:   short fibres,
B:   medium fibres,
C:   long fibres,
D:   binder

and response variable is permeability.

Under each column, proportion of each ingredient is given and they all sum up to 1 for each row(observation).

I tried to find rank of the matrix with columns as A,B,C and D(dropped response variable) in r with rankMM() in r. It is giving 4. How is this possible as by using values of other three columns we can exactly tell value under 4th column?

Comment: Are you saying that because the fourth row is ' one minus sum of other three rows' that means the matrix can't have full rank ?   If so, that is just false.  Consider the identity matrix. It also has that property. I think the point is that r = (1,1,1,1) is a 'row of a matrix.  Your equation is really $r1+r2+r3+r4 = r$  which involves 5 rows.  Of course any of these rows can be gotten from the other 4 linearly independent rows.